# Make AtomLinter eslint only alert me to syntax errors

Tags: atom-editor, eslint

Is there a way to have AtomLinter only alert me to syntax/parsing errors in my JavaScript? I don't need all the eslint style rules enforced until making a commit, at which point I have a pre-commit hook that will alert me to linting errors.

I do have a local .eslintrc file. Ideally, I could still use it for the "Fix file" command when desired.

Comment: It does this by default for me. Are you sure you did not do something extra?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have an `.eslintrc` config that it is reading from. Maybe that's causing the difference?